# Confused about false positive and false negative in confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working on binary classification for classifying cancer=1 and no-cancer=0, I use confusion matrix from sklearn, this is my confusion matrix on test set:

```
 # confusion matrix
 [[18  0]
 [ 7 15]]

 # in my reading the order is:
   TN=18
   FP=0
   FN=7
   TP=15
```

but in some tutorials, I see different ordering for FP and FN, some said same as my reading,[See here](https://uberpython.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/precision-recall-sensitivity-and-specificity/), but other said reverse of FP and FN, [see here](https://medium.com/greyatom/performance-metrics-for-classification-problems-in-machine-learning-part-i-b085d432082b).
my question is which one is true in my case? please give me a reference to be sure about the answer.

Comment: It's really a shame that software (perhaps your coding?)  doesn't label the rows and columns with the variable names used to create them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about the order of your test and prediction sets when constructing the confusion matrix. Here is a piece from one of my codes.

> cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
>
> print(cm)
>
> Output:
> [[TN FP]
>
> [ FN TP]]

However, if I used:

> cm = confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test)
>
> print(cm)
>
> Output:
> [[TN FN]
>
> [ FP TP]]

That occurs **since the predictions of the model are presented in the rows instead of columns** now. Also confusion matrices can be NxN, or the classes may not be labeled as either 0 or 1. You can also change the places of TN and TP, think what should happen if you had classes named as 9 and 10. In other words, decision of Negative/Positive signs are our decision; we say what they are (hopefully in a reasonable way).

Hope I could help, please do not hesitate to ask more.
Regards.

Comment: In my code `test_cm = confusion_matrix(y_act, y_pred)`, this means am right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, never forget that you can choose class 0 to be Pozitive rather than class 1 or vice versa. It  depends on your viewpoint. There is not a strict structure of a confusion matrix.